# A Baire category question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, baire-category

Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of real valued continuous functions converging pointwise on $\Bbb R$. Show that there exists a number $M>0$ and an interval $I \subset \Bbb R$ such that $\sup\{ |f_n(x)|:x \in I \} \le M$ for all $n$.

The idea here is to use the uniform boundedness principle or Baire category theorem, it's just a little unclear for me the best one to use, and the best way to apply it. I tried looking at the proof of the uniform boundedness principle, but for that, you need a Banach space $X$ and a normed linear space $Y$. I assume $Y$ is the real numbers, but what would I choose for $X$? Continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ under some norm making it complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint* Suppose the the contrary. Then choose an arbitrary point in $\Bbb R$, call it $x_0$. Consider the open interval $I_1=B(x_0,1)$. Then there exists $x_1$ in such that $f_{n_1}(x_1)\geqslant 1$. Choose $\varepsilon_1$ such that $I_2= B(x_1,\varepsilon_1)\subsetneq I_2$.

If we had $|f_n(x)|\leqslant 2$ for any $n>n_1$ and any $x\in I_2\smallsetminus\{x_1\}$, the claim would be true. So there exists $x_2\neq x_1$ and $n_2>n_1$ such that $f_{n_2}(x_2)\geqslant 2$. We may take $n_1<n_2$ and $x_1\neq x_2$ for finiteness conditions: deleting a finite amount of points or indices cannot alter the fact the claim doesn't hold.

Continuing, we produce a sequence of distinct points $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$, and a sequence of nested closed intervals $(\overline{I_n})_{n\geqslant 1}$ such that $x_i\in I_i$ $f_{n_i}(x_i)\geqslant i$. By Cantor's nested interval property, there exists $x\in \bigcap\limits_{i\in I} \overline{I_i}$. I claim that $y_n=f_n(x)$ cannot converge.

**ADD** Note the proof is pretty Baire-ish.

As suggested by Daniel Fischer (thought he'd post it) another solution would be to note that $$\Bbb R=\bigcup_{m\geqslant 0}\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\{x\in\Bbb R:|f_n(x)|\leqslant m\}$$ and directlly invoke Baire's theorem.

Comment: I believe you want $f_{n_i}(x)\geq i/2$ for $x\in I_i$.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Does it make a difference...?

Comment: Then you have $y_{n_i}\geq i/2$. I'm not sure you can get something similar without assuming this.

Comment: Thanks for what you've written this far guys, I will look at this later.

Comment: For Daniel Fischer's answer, what is the union over exactly? Capital M, and in the natural numbers?

Comment: @JohnnyApple Natural numbers everywhere. We want countable unions for Baire.

Comment: @JohnnyApple Yes, that's what I'm doing.

Comment: So, we know that for some m, this intersection is not nowhere dense, so that means there is, say, an open interval in $\Bbb R$ on which it is dense? But how does that give you an interval where, for ALL x, the sup is less than m?

Comment: EDIT: I see, my definition of "Not nowhere dense" was incorrect. We know that closure of the intersection contains an open interval, so we are done since this is the intersection of closed sets (since f_n are cts). Now, where did we use that f_n converge pointwise?

Comment: @JohnnyApple Just sit down, grab a piece of paper and think about it for a second. =)

Comment: I did...is this correct: intersection over n of $\{|f_n(x)|<M\}$ contains some interval $I$. Thus the limit over n is also in $I$. Thus the limsup, thus the sup over $I$ is $\le$ to M?